# remove all objects from NSMutable array

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

i used following method to rmove all objects from an NSMutableArray

[myData removeAllObjects];

but it gives an runtime error

here is the error

OrgProject(3934,0xa0719500) malloc: *** error for object 0x5f5ca30: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”

please help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have released some of object of the array before removing it from this array

Answer (score 2):

It looks like on of the objects was released to often. This often happens when you release an autoreleased object without explicitly retaining it, for example. As the array retains its objects, this bug hides very well until this point.

It should be easy to find out *which* object is the problem here, and then look how it is created and what retain/release/autorelease messages you send to it.